# "except Exception" on asyncio.gather() does not catch KeyboardInterrupt

Tags: python-asyncio

I have many tasks running and one raises a KeyboardInterrupt (because, in fact, I am pressing ctrl-c at a given time and this seems to be caught by one of the actions in the task before it is caught by the root code; in the below example it is simulated with `raise KeyboardInterrupt`).

The code below never catches this KeyboardInterrupt.

```py
import asyncio
import logging

class Cow:
    async def whisper(self):
        while True:
            print("moo")
            await asyncio.sleep(1)
            raise KeyboardInterrupt


async def main():
    tasks = [asyncio.create_task(Cow().whisper()) for i in range(3)]

    try:
        results = await asyncio.gather(*tasks, return_exceptions=False)
    except Exception:
        logging.exception("interrupted")
try:
    asyncio.run(main())
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    logging.error("ctrl-c pressed")
```

complaint:

```
    ERROR:asyncio:Task exception was never retrieved
    future: <Task finished name='Task-1' coro=<main() done...>
```

if I change the first `except Exception` to `except KeyboardInterrupt`, the exception does get retrieved properly.

I was reasoning that, since KeyboardInterrupt inherits from Exception, both should be caught by `except Exception`. Why is it not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, as so many times I figured it out as I was writing the question: `KeyboardInterrupt` does not actually inherit from `Exception`. Both inherit from `BaseException` directly.